# Error when getting information for file "folder/": input/output error

Tags: 20.04, mount, usb-drive, sd-card, media

I've searched for some similar questions for my problem but couldn't find solution. I've flash drive that I copied some files from window OS for a long time ago,and I cannot open them on ubuntu, getting error `**This location could not be displayed** Error when getting information for file "folder/": input/output error`, and some folders inside show `this file is of an unknown type`,
[image]
how can it be fixed ? there are some important files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've provided few details; I'd suggest reading the full error messages; as the IO errors could be related to actual physical errors (*hardware problems*) or logical errors (*related to the unstated file-system such as an unclean file-system*) but you've provided few details for us to help. You mention 20.04, but not if it's 20.04 Server, or 20.04 Desktop or something else; let alone what *fs* you're having issues with.

Comment: @guiverc I've updated question, you can check the full error, and i am on 20.04 Desktop, idk what else can i provide you...

Comment: The file-system still hasn't been mentioned; as it's located in the /media/ folder it's probably an external device; but is it NTFS, ext4 or something else?  Was it cleanly removed when last used (*if not then it maybe unclean & thus logical errors can exist until file-system checks clean up issues due to unclean removal for example*).  Your file also reads like it was an erased file from Trash; that file may exist on another computer (where it was deleted; you'll only not get an error in that case on the computer where the file was moved into the trash for example).

Comment: `/dev/sda3: UUID="d6014b03-2bc9-48a3-9ad8-8eae69a33cf1" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="654edd9c-09a7-48e0-a08b-6d126c3c6900"`
`/dev/sda5: UUID="36bbd337-eb37-40a4-bb7a-62db57ac24ce" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="fcef0b0e-20ab-4f16-816a-13b3d673cb05"`
`
you mean this ?